# What is the shortcut to focus back on the Atom editor when focus is on the tree-view? And the opposite?

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

Is there in atom.io a shortcut to get the focus back on the editor (maybe even on a particular pane) when the tree has the focus?

I've checked on the documentation but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just hit escape. This works on Mac OS.

Comment: I' stunned. Thanks! How the #$%* could I miss that!?

Comment: I have been using the mouse to re-focus for a year or more :(

Comment: "CTRL + 0" is focus on the tree-view on Mac

Answer (score 4):

On fedora 29 Workstation(Gnome desktop), Linux.
Use the keybinding (keyboard shortcuts) , `ALT+\`, for toggle between  "Tree View" and Editor area.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a Ctrl+[number] combination for switching between panels, tree view and editor.

You can add the following lines to your keymap.cson file *[1]* to change the default Atom keybindings.

```
'.tree-view':
  'ctrl-1': 'tree-view:unfocus'

'.platform-win32':
  'ctrl-3': 'tree-view:toggle-focus'
```

This would result in:

Ctrl + 3 to focus on the tree-view
Ctrl + 1 to go back to editor

[1]: To access the keymap file, type `ctrl + ,` to access Atom settings and go to Keybindings >> "Your keymap file" 
Ps. remember to maintain the indentation